# How to escape a pipe ( | ) symbol for url_encode in python

Tags: python

I am facing a problem with urllib.url_encode  in python. Bets explained with some code:

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> params = {'p' : '1 2 3 4 5&6', 'l' : 'ab|cd|ef'}
>>> urlencode(params)
'p=1+2+3+4+5%266&l=ab%7Ccd%7Cef'
```

I want to keep the pipes ('|') in to l parameter. can you please tell me how?

The result should be

```
'p=1+2+3+4+5%266&l=ab|cd|ef'
```

PS: I do not want to put together the URL manually, but use urlencode for that.

Thanks 
-Pat

Comment: If you need the pipes in there, you are not urlencoding, simple as that.

Comment: urlencode and then replace `%7C` with `|`

Comment: So you basically want to URL-encode and then revert part of the encoding? Why do you URL-encode then? It seems to me that URLs with pipe symbols can create problems. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298404/the-connection-was-reset-asp-net)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Convert a mapping object or a sequence of two-element tuples to a
>   “percent-encoded” string[...]

The [urlencode()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html?highlight=urlencode#urllib.urlencode) method is acting as expected.  If you want to prevent the encoding then you can first encode the entire object and then replace the encoded characters with pipes.

```
>>> u = urlencode(params)
>>> u.replace('%7C', '|')
'p=1+2+3+4+5%266&l=ab|cd|ef'
```

Comment: I thought replacing | with \| or something before urlencoding should wor, but your solution is also OK. Thanks

Comment: Adding the standard escape character `\\` would then just be converted to %5C. The only way to solve it would be to replace it after it has been encoded.

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler in Python 3:

```
urllib.parse.urlencode(params, safe='|')
```