# Pipe Symbol not working in URL of Codeigneiter in different different browsers

Tags: php, codeigniter, special-characters

I am having issue with **PIPE** symbol (**|**) in my URL of codeigneiter. It is converted into some browsers and not giving results. How can i solve this issue. I use row_urlencode PHP function, but it is also not working for me.

Comment: I am facing issue in local environment. '|' symbol convert into %7c.

Comment: http://www.learnqtp.com/forums/Thread-Issues-with-Browser-Name-which-has-Pipe-Symbol

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317588/how-to-escape-a-pipe-symbol-for-url-encode-in-python

Comment: update config file...
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'special characters list';